# how do I list files in the father directory?

Tags: unix

Per Example, I'm in folder A which is a subdirectory of folder B, meaning B is the "father folder" of A. Is there a way to use the ls command to give me the contents of directory A while I'm currently on B?

Comment: If A is a subdirectory of B, then B is the parent. Just so you know. `/a/b` is a subdirectory of `/a`, for example, not the other way around.

Comment: What research have you done on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls ..` works for listing the files in the folder above the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in B and need to list A (parent)

#### have full path of files/directories + attributes

ls -ltra $(pwd)/..

#### have files name + attributes

ls -ltra ..